# Mapping super types and fetching a subtype

Tags: java, java-8

Heres a design question. Would it be a bad practice to store a map of Foo objects where Foo is a superclass and cast the lookup to more specific objects? ie.:

```
Map<Integer, Foo> lookup = new HashMap<>();
lookup.put(0, new Bar()); //Bar extends Foo
lookup.put(1, new Fizz()); // Fizz extends Foo

public Bar getBarById (int barId){
   (Bar)lookup.get(barId);
}
```

How brittle would the above approach be? Is there a better way in Java8 or a better design pattern that would allow me to do something similar?

Comment: The answer depends on what the objects are used for and why you are storing them.  For example, if the objects implement a standard interface that you wish to use, you could use that interface for the Map value type and not worry about typecasting.

Comment: @JEarls well after the lookup I want to access fields on the lookup up object. The interface does not have all those methods. Only the class bar for example had getname() so I would need to know the type before I can use that method

Comment: Compared to which alternative?

Answer (score 0):

It's good idea you have, but it looks like you need to split the objects up. You won't know which type your pulling out of the map unless your going to track their key.

So if you enter a new Bar() with the key 0 you'll need to store that in a list or something so when you want to just call the methods for Bar you can look at your ArrayList of Bar object ids.

```
Map<Integer, Foo> lookup = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<Integer> listOfBar = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> listOfFizz = new ArrayList<>();

lookup.put(0, new Bar()); //Bar extends Foo
listOfBar.add(0);

lookup.put(1, new Fizz()); // Fizz extends Foo
listOfFizz.add(1);

//in Method to return Bars 
if(listOfBar.size() != 0){
int k = listOfBar.get(0);
Bar b = lookup.get(k);
return b;


}
```

So now all the ids for that particular object can just be accessed using the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

The original code won't work because **getBarbyId()** will fail when you give it the id of a "Fizz" (id #1 in your example):

```
// ClassCastException:  System.out.println(this.getBarById(1).getClass().getSimpleName());
```

You could accomplish the same thing with an ArrayList, but the important part is that if you want your own accessor you should make it **getFooById**, even if you don't have the ability to change the Foo class.

Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    class Foo {
        // Assume defined elsewhere and we can't change it
    }

    class Bar extends Foo {}
    class Fizz extends Foo {}

    public Foo getFooById(int id) {
        return fooList.get(id);
    }

    ArrayList<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<>();

    Main() {
        fooList.add(0, new Bar());      // keys optional here, unless you are 
        fooList.add(1, new Fizz());     // looking for specific entries later

        for (int i=0; i < fooList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("foo:  " + i + " " + getFooById(i).getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
foo:  0 Bar
foo:  1 Fizz
```